# Are there non-commuting self - adjoint operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am currently working through a set of lecture notes on operator theory.

For self - adjoint operators, I just showed that, if $B_1$ and $B_2 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},)$ are self - adjoint then $B_1B_2$ is self - adjoint if and only if $B_1$ and $B_2$ commute. (Here, $\mathcal{H}$ denotes a Hilbert Space, and $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ stands for the space of bounded operators defined on $\mathcal{H}$.

Now I am wondering - are there actually self - adjoint operators that do not commute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example given by draks in the comments: the matrices 
$B_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&i\\
-i&0
\end{pmatrix}$ do not commute: $$\left[B_1,B_2\right]_-=2i\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}\neq 0$$